Animations in Framer Motion
I was trying to implement Framer Motion, to understand how it works, in a personal project of mine.
For now, I wrote the following code (100% working), in these two components:

Modal.jsx
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function Modal({ title, children, onClose }) {
  return createPortal(
    <>
      <div className="backdrop" onClick={onClose} />
      <motion.dialog
        variants={{
          open: { opacity: 1, translateY: 0 },
          closed: { opacity: 0, translateY: 30 },
        }}
        initial="closed"
        animate="open"
        exit="closed"
        open
        className="modal"
      >
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        {children}
      </motion.dialog>
    </>,
    document.getElementById("modal")
  );
}


NewChallenge.jsx
import { useContext, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import { ChallengesContext } from "../store/challenges-context.jsx";
import Modal from "./Modal.jsx";
import images from "../assets/images.js";

export default function NewChallenge({ onDone }) {
  const title = useRef();
  const description = useRef();
  const deadline = useRef();

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const { addChallenge } = useContext(ChallengesContext);

  function handleSelectImage(image) {
    setSelectedImage(image);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const challenge = {
      title: title.current.value,
      description: description.current.value,
      deadline: deadline.current.value,
      image: selectedImage,
    };

    if (
      !challenge.title.trim() ||
      !challenge.description.trim() ||
      !challenge.deadline.trim() ||
      !challenge.image
    ) {
      return;
    }

    onDone();
    addChallenge(challenge);
  }

  return (
    <Modal title="New Challenge" onClose={onDone}>
      <form id="new-challenge" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <p>
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          <input ref={title} type="text" name="title" id="title" />
        </p>

        <p>
          <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
          <textarea ref={description} name="description" id="description" />
        </p>

        <p>
          <label htmlFor="deadline">Deadline</label>
          <input ref={deadline} type="date" name="deadline" id="deadline" />
        </p>

        <motion.ul
          id="new-challenge-images"
          variants={{
            open: { transition: { staggerChildren: 0.05 } },
          }}
          initial="closed"
          animate="open"
        >
          {images.map((image) => (
            <motion.li
              key={image.alt}
              onClick={() => handleSelectImage(image)}
              className={selectedImage === image ? "selected" : undefined}
              variants={{
                closed: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 },
                open: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
              }}
            >
              <img {...image} />
            </motion.li>
          ))}
        </motion.ul>

        <p className="new-challenge-actions">
          <button type="button" onClick={onDone}>
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button>Add Challenge</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
}



All animations, after various tests, work correctly, in particular:

The animation in Modal.jsx, animates the <dialog> with a fade-in-from-bottom style animation

The animations in New Challenge.jsx animates the list <ul> by setting an animation delay on the elements of the list with staggerChildren and the list items <li> with a bounce style animation.


As mentioned above, everything works and the animations are triggered correctly.
What I wanted to understand is, where does the list <ul> get the initial state "closed" from? From the Modal?
Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?
I am not an expert in using this library, but I find it very useful and would like to learn how to use it in the best possible way.
Could anyone help me understand?
